# Running DBCC on NON-READABLE replica

Tags: dbcc, sql-server-2022, standard-edition, basic-availability-groups

Since the system databases are not duplicated in a AG environment, I want to be able to run DBCC on them on a weekly basis and I would also like to be able to run DBCC on any databases where the AG shows as Primary on that server.

Is there a way to create a maintenance plan that would step through each database on the server, checking if its in a readable state or not and then run DBCC on it, and skip those that are in a non-readable state?